# Relation of two squares

Tags: c#

My homework is to make a program which draws 2 squares, and than determines if they cross, touch, inside of one another, or neither.

I use a two point system: the first is the top-left, the other is the bottom-right. Then, i draw the lines between them.

Can you, please, tell me a simple algorithm which determines which of these 4 cases happen?

Crossing:

```
 ┌────┐
 │  ┌──────────┐
 │  │ │        │
 └──│─┘        │
    └──────────┘
```

Touching:

```
 ┌────┐
 │    │──────────┐
 │    │          │
 └────┘          │
      └──────────┘
```

Inside of one another:

```
  ┌──────────┐
  │  ┌────┐  │
  │  └────┘  │
  └──────────┘
```

Neither:

```
 ┌────┐
 │    │  ┌──────────┐
 │    │  │          │
 └────┘  │          │
         └──────────┘
```

Comment: don't be so lazy and at least look at the C# documentation, you have a wonderful class named "Rectangle", maybe it can give you some help?

Comment: You can use the Google to find simple bounding box collision detection algorithms, but you should really spend a little time thinking about it before copy/pasting a solution, the point of the exercise is to think about a problem that seems to have an obvious solution that you might have a hard time describing algorithmically off the cuff.

Comment: Solve an easier problem. Drop down two dimensions. Can you determine if two points are equal?  If you can't solve that problem, you can't solve the harder problem. Can you determine if two lines overlap?  If you can't solve that problem then you can't solve the harder problem.  Solve those problems first and then the solution to the harder problem will be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I won't put any code for you, because it's not really a language specific problem, and because it's for you to do. But here's some pointers:

- You have two intervals on the X axis, and two on the Y axis
- It's well known how to determine if two intervals overlap. You can also determine whether one interval is entirely inside the other.
- For the squares to overlap, there's a simple condition you need to test for. Think of what it is.
- Bonus: you can work out the overlap area as well.